# Xamarin.iOS status bar keeps color in the corner when changing it and the orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-darkmode

My application supports the iOS system darkmode change. However it got a little bit tricky with the status bar color but in the end i managed to change it aswell.

My problem is, when you are on an iPad in Portrait mode and you switch the Theme, and then tilt the iPad to Landscape mode, the extension of the status bar keeps the old color (See screenshot below)

I don't know if this is just a nasty bug or if i'm doing something wrong. In case it's a bug i would love to have a workaround for this.

Here's how i'm changing the status bar color in a `CustomRenderer` (in this example to Light Mode)

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
{
    UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF").ToUIColor();
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
}
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF").ToUIColor();
```

This gets called in the `TraitCollectionDidChange` function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used Frame to add a custom status bar. When it runs into the landscape its width remains the portrait's value. Try to change it to autolayout like:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
{
    UIView statusBar = new UIView();
    statusBar.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);

    statusBar.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
    statusBar.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.TopAnchor).Active = true;
    statusBar.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
    statusBar.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame.Height).Active = true;
}
```

### Update

If you want to change the color back to the original value, try the code here:

```
public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(UITraitCollection previousTraitCollection)
{
    base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection);

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        UIView statusBar;
        if (window.ViewWithTag(4) != null)
        {
            statusBar = window.ViewWithTag(4);
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar = new UIView();
            statusBar.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            statusBar.Tag = 4;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
            statusBar.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
            statusBar.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.TopAnchor).Active = true;
            statusBar.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
            statusBar.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame.Height).Active = true;
        }                    

        if (previousTraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light)
        {
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want, could you please add more descriptions about your issue?

BTW, if you want to add some transition, try this:

```
UIView.Animate(0.3, () =>
{
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
});
```

Comment: This would work fine, but when i for example turn the iPad to Landscape, switch to DarkMode and then go back to Portrait and switch back to LightMode after a milli second the Bar turns back to the dark color and ONLY the extra bit that was in the wrong color before is now in the right color, any idea?

Comment: Do you want to revert back the status bar's color when returning to light mode? There will be a transition when changing the mode.
I update my code above to complete the whole process.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm experiencing more troubles with the Statusbar (& NavigationBar) color since updating to Xamarin 4.6, i will create a seperate post and come back here when i manage to fix it

Comment: @EliasJohannes Did you mean Xamarin Forms 4.6? But I thought this thread was talking about issues on Xamarin iOS. Did you have some update about this topic?